# Android ADB error for Appium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, test-automation-framework, mobile, appium, mobile-automation

The Android Debug Bridge (ADB) error below is given when running application on Eclipse.

How can I fix this?

```
Checking if an update is available
Launching Appium server with command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --platform-name Android --platform-version 23 --automation-name Appium --log-no-color
info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.16 (REV ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d)
info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"address":"127.0.0.1","logNoColors":true,"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"23","automationName":"Appium"}
info: Console LogLevel: debug
Update not available
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"appPackage":"com.android.calculator2","appActivity":"com.android.calculator2.Calculator","browserName":"Android","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Galaxy S6","version":"6.0.1"}}
info: Client User-Agent string: undefined
info: [debug] The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : version
info: [debug] Didn't get app but did get Android package, will attempt to launch it on the device
info: [debug] Creating new appium session 3515ed17-27c1-4a5e-bb48-db47b4b19235
info: Starting android appium
info: [debug] Getting Java version
info: Java version is: 1.8.0_111
info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present

error: Unhandled error: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Users\Laksitha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools;C:\Users\Laksitha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\build-tools'

at Error (native)
at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:761:18)
at exports.getDirectories (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\helpers.js:100:18)
at [object Object].ADB.checkSdkBinaryPresent (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:97:25)
at [object Object].ADB.checkAdbPresent (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:134:8)
at Function.ADB.createADB (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:73:7)
at [object Object].androidCommon.initAdb (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-common.js:1083:9)
at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:607:21
at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:246:17
at iterate (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:146:13)
at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:157:25
at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:248:21
at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:612:34
at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-common.js:1077:12)
at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-common.js:1064:12)
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:742:7)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:1016:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1184:11)
at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
at Pipe.close (net.js:484:11) context: [POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"appPackage":"com.android.calculator2","appActivity":"com.android.calculator2.Calculator","browserName":"Android","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Galaxy S6","version":"6]
```

Comment: Looks like you know what the problem is, you highlighted it. Did you check those files exist ? no such file or directory 'C:\Users\Laksitha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools;C:\Users\Laksitha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\build-tools

Comment: YES those files are exist and User variables looks like that --->   ANDROID_HOME C:\Users\Laksitha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools;C:\Users\Laksitha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your environment variable is configured wrongly. Set the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable to

```
C:\Users\Laksitha\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
```

instead of

```
C:\Users\Laksitha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools;C:\Users\L‌​aksitha\AppData\Loca‌​l\Android\sdk\platfo‌​rm-tools
```